# Why does PyCharm after running any code gives out the same result (Hi, PyCharm)?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have recently started learning programming in Python and I'm using PyCharm as a text reader. I was trying out a few simple codes which I was following from a tutorial. These are the codes that I've tried:

```
Print("Hello World")
```

and also a simple calculator code:

```
num1 = input("Enter a number")
num2 = input("Enter another number")
sum = num1 + num2

print(sum)
```

Instead of getting as a result "Hello World" or being asked what numbers I want to input, I just get the exact same thing:

```
C:\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/Roman Moraru/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py"
Hi, PyCharm

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't know why this "Hi, PyCharm" keeps being the result of the program. I've looked around and haven't seen anybody with the same problem, so I'm kinda lost here.

Comment: Did you save your code file after the change?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't even been able to properly understand PyCharm, but I don't think I saved the file,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within PyCharm, you may just need to keep track of which script you are running in PyCharm.  Right-click the script you want to run and choose run or debug.  You can also search for 'Hi, Pycharm' in your code to find the script that is running with menu: edit: find: find in files.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, you just need to switch the configuration from 'Main' to 'Current File' in the right hand corner on top.

Comment: while this is probably correct, a bit more context and/or screenshot would be appreciated. references to PyCharm documentation as well. (indeed you are refering to something called "run configurations" see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#config-folders which is a pretty decent guide) : specifically here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-without-any-previous-configuring.html